# What is the use of \r\n in the SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to understand a piece of SQL query in a springboot project in which \r\n is being used multiple times in the query. I'm not understanding the signification of this(\r\n) in accessing data from a database table.
If anyone can tell me the use of '\r\n' in SQL queries.

Comment: Take a look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059142/reading-r-carriage-return-vs-n-newline-from-console-with-getc/10059171

Answer (score 0):

That is just white space that is ignored. The query was probably written on a Microsoft Windows system, which has interesting ideas about what a line break should look like.