# What's the difference between \n and \r\n?

Tags: string, special-characters, line-endings

They both mean "new line" but when is one used over the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`\r\n` is a **Windows** Style

`\n` is a **POSIX** Style

`\r` is a old **pre-OS X Macs** Style, **Modern Mac's** using **POSIX** Style.

---

`\r` is a carriage return and `\n` is a line feed, in *old computers* where it not have monitor, have only printer to get out programs result to user, if you want get printing from staring of new line from left, you must get `\n` for *Line Feed*, and `\r` for get *Carriage return* to the most left position, this is from old computers syntax saved to this time on **Windows** platform.

Comment: CR+LF is commonly used in many networking protocols (like HTTP), regardless of the OS used to transmit the data. `\r` is commonly mapped to CR whenever the target system uses ASCII or Unicode as its character system.  (If the target system uses EBCDIC, then `\r` may not have a mapping.)  `\n` is trickier, as it depends on context.  It's often mapped to an ASCII/Unicode LINE FEED, but it's not always that simple.  Answers to the "Possible Duplicate" question has details.

Comment: You can see the HTTP spec from here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html CRLF (carriage return line feed)

Answer (score 15):

\n means new line. It means that the cursor must go to the next line.

\r means carriage return. It means that the cursor should go back to the beginning of the line.

Unix programs usually only needs a new line (\n).

Windows programs usually need both.

Comment: Coming in 9 years later, you wrote Windows and Windows programs, instead of MacOS and Windows

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong and that Windows and Mac behave differently. But since I'm not Mac expert, I'll remove the line about mac entirely and leave it to more knowledgeable people.

Comment: Prior to Mac OS X, Macs used `\r` alone as its line terminator. As Mac OS X / OS X / macOS is a Unix, the old convention was dropped in favor of the standard Unix convention of a single linefeed.

Answer (score 8):

\n is a newline only, \r\n is a newline and a carriage return (i.e. move the cursor to the left).

Answer (score 4):

Different Operating Systems handle newlines in a different way. Here is a short list of the most common ones:
DOS and Windows

They expect a newline to be the combination of two characters, namely '\r\n' (or 13 followed by 10).

Unix (and hence Linux as well)

Unix uses a single '\n' to indicate a new line.

Mac

Macs use a single '\r'.

so this causes problems when u port your app from windows to mac when u're using folder path's and alike.

Comment: Mac since Mac OS X uses \n

Answer (score 3):

'\n' is the default in Unix, '\r\n' is the default in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is how new line is represented in operating systems Windows (\r\n)and linux (\n)

On Unix the \r is a Carriage Return (CR) and the
\n a Line Feed (LF) which together happen to be the be Windows newline
identifier and you are replacing them with a Unix newline identifier.

On Windows the \r is a CR, too, but the \n is a combination of CR and LF. So
effectively you are trying to replace CR+CR+LF with CR+LF. Doesn't make much
sense, does it.

From "perldoc perlop":
All systems use the virtual ""\n"" to represent a line terminator,
called a "newline". There is no such thing as an unvarying, physical
newline character. It is only an illusion that the operating system,
device drivers, C libraries, and Perl all conspire to preserve. Not all
systems read ""\r"" as ASCII CR and ""\n"" as ASCII LF. For example, on
a Mac, these are reversed, and on systems without line terminator,
printing ""\n"" may emit no actual data. In general, use ""\n"" when you
mean a "newline" for your system, but use the literal ASCII when you
need an exact character. For example, most networking protocols expect
and prefer a CR+LF (""\015\012"" or ""\cM\cJ"") for line terminators,
and although they often accept just ""\012"", they seldom tolerate just
""\015"". If you get in the habit of using ""\n"" for networking, you
may be burned some day.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between different operating systems, on Windows, the newline character is `\r\n` while on Linux it is just `\n` Mac OSX has just `\r` its really just a matter of what the designers of the OS made it to be

Comment: Mac since Mac OS X uses \n