# Seperate 1 Textarea line as array to store them in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

so i want to use multible Data, 1 line as a array string seperate from the Textarea in the Backend from my NodeJS Web Application to save them as a new Data in the Collection:

```
{"_id":"someid","Name":"Tim"},{"_id":"someid","Name":"Steve"}
```

This in a Textarea:

```
Tim
Steve
John
```

so now in the Backend shuld the Data store in a array to create new MongoDB Data:

```
var data = ['Tim', 'Steve', 'John'];
```

I dont know how to seperate the Datas to a Array in the Backend...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string containing the textarea's contents, you can call `string.split("\n")` to split it into an array (using the newline character as a delimiter).

So if you had a variable called `textarea` which contained the textarea's value, it would look something like this:

```js
var textarea = "..."; // Get this from somewhere
var data = textarea.split("\n");
```

If you want to provide cross-platform support, you should also handle Windows-style line breaks (`\r\n`) by replacing them with POSIX line breaks before calling `.split("\n")`, like so: `string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n")`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821814/14287233) for further explanation surrounding Windows/POSIX line breaks.