# What's the difference between this characters?

Tags: html, windows, linux, web-applications, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

I really would like to know what's the difference between `\n` , `\r` , `\t` , `chr(13)` , how they are used in a web application, in which OS, and so on.

For example, can you confirm that windows uses `\n\r` for the newline, while of linux uses just `\n` right? It would be interesting to know these things.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n

Comment: @Richard86 - No mention of `\t` in the question you linked.

Comment: @Oded I'm sorry, you're right.

Comment: I have to agree with @Oded here, and I know it's a little picky but... my first impression on viewing this question was that it was indeed a duplicate but when I clicked through to the duplicate indicated by Richard86 above, it didn't, in fact, have any reference to \t in the question. As an aside, perhaps there is scope for admins to insert a link to the duplicate question inside the "marked as duplicate" box below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\n - Line Feed - 0x0A - 10 decimal - LF

\r - Carriage Return - 0X0D - 13 decimal - CR

\t - tab - 0x09 - 9 decimal - ht (horizontal tab)

For detailed hex, decimal values refer:
http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html

CR+LF: DEC TOPS-10, RT-11 and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes, CP/M, MP/M, DOS (MS-DOS, PC-DOS, etc.), Atari TOS, OS/2, Microsoft Windows, Symbian OS, Palm OS

LF+CR: Acorn BBC spooled text output.

CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9

LF:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (GNU/Linux, AIX, Xenix, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others. However, in tty 'raw mode', CR+LF is used for output and CR is used for input.

RS:    QNX pre-POSIX implementation.

For more details on \n, \r \t refer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_tab

To use \n \r \t in html for you can use the below codes:

```
\n in html == &#10; or &#x0A; linux, Unix and Mac OS X

\r in html == &#13; or &#x0D; Mac(classic)

\r\n in html == &#13;&#10; or &#x0D;&#x0A; Windows

\t in html == &#9; or &#x09;
```

Answer (score 7):

These are character escape sequences in many languages (c, c++, java, javascript, .NET to name a few). They directly translate to the equivalent ASCII values (you posted this as `chr(13)` which in one language would produce a character based on that ASCII value).

Their meanings are:

```
\n == chr(13) == carriage return
\r == chr(10) == line feed
\t == chr (9) == tab
```

These all come from control characters for printers, in turn coming from typewriters.

> A carriage return brings the typewriter to the beginning of the line.
>
> A line feed brings the typewriter to the next line.
>
> A tab moves the typewriter to the next tab stop.

A combination of line feed and carriage return is needed to bring the typewriter to the start of the next line.

The differences between windows and unix stem from the different decisions on the different platforms on how to represent a new line. Unix went with carriage return (probably also to save space), Windows with both. Macs used to use linefeeds for the same.

Comment: Windows tends to use \r\n as a line separator (the opposite order compared to the question).

Answer (score 1):

The `13` in `chr(13)` is the ASCII code for carriage return. There are numerous ASCII charts to look at for more codes to use with `chr()`.

- Windows uses a carriage return \ newline (`\r\n`) to denote a new line.
- MacOS uses a carriage return only (`\r`)
- Linux and Unix generally uses a new line only (`\n`).