# How are \r \t and \n different from one another?

Tags: php, escaping, character

In the code below, I don't know how these characters are different functionally from one another: \r \t \n.  Does anyone have an explanation or description for these?

Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sorting words in a block of text by length</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sorting words in a block of text by length</h1>

<?php

$myText = <<<END_TEXT
But think not that this famous town has 
only harpooneers, cannibals, and 
bumpkins to show her visitors. Not at 
all. Still New Bedford is a queer place. 
Had it not been for us whalemen, that 
tract of land would this day perhaps 
have been in as howling condition as the 
coast of Labrador.
END_TEXT;

echo "<h2>The text:</h2>";
echo "<div style=\"width: 30em;\">$myText</div>";

$myText = preg_replace( "/[\,\.]/", "", $myText );
$words = array_unique( preg_split( "/[ \n\r\t]+/", $myText ) );
usort( $words, create_function( '$a, $b', 'return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
' ) );

echo "<h2>The sorted words:</h2>";
echo "<div style=\"width: 30em;\">";

foreach ( $words as $word ) {
    echo "$word ";
}
echo "</div>";

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: Exact duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009038/whats-the-difference-between-this-characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009038/whats-the-difference-between-this-characters)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`\n` is a symbol for new line

`\t` is a symbol for tab

and `\r` is for 'return'

You can find more information here: [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

Comment: Thank you, Pablo Lemurr.

Answer (score 18):

The `\n` symbol means literally *new line*. This will go to the start of the next new line.

The `\t` symbol means *add a tab* (which is usually 4 spaces but can easily be 2 or 8 depending on the context).

The `\r` symbol is no more used that often. It means *carriage return* which means *go to the start of the line*. It was used together with `\n` for being sure even "old" printers would get to the beginning of the next line.