# How would I print multiple lines of text in a single print statement?

Tags: python, string, line

The idea would be this:

```
a = input("insert name: ")
a
print("hi ", a, "!")
print("hello", a, "!")
print("good morning", a, "!")
```

but I need to know if there's a way to get all that prints in 1 unique thing but wrapping text kinda like this: print("hi ", a, "!" **wrap** "hello", a, "!" **wrap** "good morning", a, "!")

Ty in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

- `print("hi ", a, "!\n", "hello", a, "!\n", "good morning", a, "!")` - using the `\n` newline **control character** (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423001/how-are-r-t-and-n-different-from-one-another) for more info).
- A generator for the same sort of thing, but easier since it inserts the `\n` for you:

```py
def join(text):
  for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = [item if isinstance(item, str) else ''.join(item) for item in text[i]]
  lines = [' '.join(item) for item in text]
  return '\n'.join(lines)

# Usage:
print(join([[["hi ", a, "!"]], ["hello", [a, "!"]], ["good morning", a, "!"]]))

# Equal to:
print("hi " + a + "!")  # See how nested items (e.g [a, "!"] in ["hello", [a, "!"]]) represent simple concatenation (the equivalent of `+` in `print()`)
print("hello", a + "!")  # while sister items (e.g "good morning" and a in ["good morning", a, "!"]) represent joining with space (the equivalent of ',' in `print()`)
print("good morning", a, "!")
```

Explanation:

1. Go through and find where to concatenate, and where to delimit, strings.

   1a. `for i in range(len(text)):`: loop through the array, storing the current array index

   1b. `[item if isinstance(item, str) else ''.join(item) for item in text[i]]`: Let's break this down. We take the current item - represented by `text[i]` (since this is inside the `for` loop, each item looks something like `["hello", [a, "!"]]`) - and loop through it. So, the variable `item` will have values that look either like `"hello"` or `[a, "!"]`. Next, we use `isinstance` to check if the the item is a string. If so, we just leave it. Otherwise, it's an array, so we concatenate all of the values in it together with no delimiter. So, the full example would be: `[[["hi ", "dog", "!"]], ["hello", ["dog", "!"]], ["good morning", "dog", "!"]]` becomes `[["hi dog!"], ["hello", "dog!"], ["good morning", "dog", "!"]]`
2. `lines = [' '.join(item) for item in text]`: creates an array with each item in `text`, a nested array, but joined together using . This results in flattening the nested array into a basic 1D array, with each individual array of items replaced by a version separated by spaces (e.g `[['hi', 'my', 'friend'], ['how', 'are', 'you']]` becomes `['hi my friend', 'how are you']`)
3. `'\n'.join(lines)` joins together each string in the flat array, using the `\n` control character (see link above) as a delimiter (e.g `['hi my friend', 'how are you']` becomes `'hi my friend\nhow are you'`)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in Python. Here is one using the [`.format(*args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of the `str` class:

```
print("hi, {0}!\nhello, {0}!\ngood morning, {0}!".format(a))
```

Notice the `'\n'` character for a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just print it with one statement:

```
print(f"hi {}! hello {a}! good morning {a}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the newline character, `'\n'`:

```
print("hi ", a, "!\n", "hello", a, "!\n", "good morning", a, "!")
```

Of course, you can use all sorts of string formatting, like f-strings, `str.format` and `printf`-style formatting.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this answer so I can improve it

Answer (score 0):

By default, print commands performs a new line operation. But you can change that newline to something else:

```
a = input("insert name: ")
a
print("hi ", a, "!", end=" ")
print("hello", a, "!", end=" ")
print("good morning", a, "!", end="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the string into chunks in a generator to make a list, which we can join with newlines

```
n = 5

wrapped = '\n'.join([string[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(string),n)])

print(wrapped)
```

EDIT:

Sorry misunderstood what was meant by 'wrap'.

You could do something like `print(sentence1, sentence2, … , sep="\n")`, using the `.format` method suggested by others for each sentence.