# server copies file and save text on single row

Tags: html, windows, linux, ftp

I have a .html file with some scripts in it. Works fine on localhost but when I copy it on a server (use ftp) it copies with all text in one line, so of course scripts don't work. How can I fix this?

Is windows->linux problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a CRLF / LF problem (resulting from the different ways operating systems handle newline characters).

See:

- [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: I know the difference... how do I fix it? Is not my dream to type everything again on the server.

Comment: A global search-and-replace is an easy way. Most programs handle the newline characters sensibly already. You may have an entirely different problem, though. I recommend you add more detail to your question.

Comment: Nope... that was it. Changed the editor, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, `cat -A <file>` will display UNIX endlines as `$`, DOS endlines as `^M`, and tab characters as `^I`. It can show you exactly which characters are missing.

```
$ cat -A file.html

<body>^M
Hello, world!^M
</body>^M
```

You can convert DOS endlines to UNIX with:

```
$ dos2unix file.html
```