# Pattern.UNIX_LINES in regex with Java

Tags: java, regex

Hi from the java doc here the following:

> **UNIX_LINES**
>
> `public static final int UNIX_LINES`
>
> Enables Unix lines mode.
>
> In this mode, only the `'\n'` line terminator is recognized in the
>   behavior of `.`, `^`, and `$`.
>
> Unix lines mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression
>   `(?d)`.

Does anybody have other words to define what it serves? I understood that "\n" escape sequence is recognized only after `.`, `^`, and `$`.
Apparently I am misunderstood.

Comment: You may want to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline as well.

Comment: @devnull Can I have a quick example? I understand the difference between \n and \r and so forth but when I try something like pattern:"abc$" matchengine:"abc\n"  it appears to not be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as how they apply specifically to regex behavior; `.`, `^`, and `$` depend on the definition of a line feed to function.

- `.` matches anything but a line break
- `^` can match the beginning of a line
- `$` can match the end of a line.

Each of these depend on the correct definition of where a line terminates.  The `UNIX_LINES` setting instructs it to strictly define the line terminator per the standard Unix definition.  By default, it defines it more broadly, [as seen in the Pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt)

As far as matching "abc\n", I assume you are using `Pattern.matches`, or something like it, which must match the entire input?  `^` and `$` are zero-width.  They can match on either side of a newline, but will not consume the newline character.  You can consume the `\n` by simply putting it in your pattern, such as `abc\n`, or you could also use the `$` character somewhat as you indicated, like `abc\n$`, or if you're feeling frisky `(?m)abc$$$$\n$$`.

[DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) and [MULTILINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) modes might also be of use to you, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I will try to explain it on `.` since same rule apply for `^` and `$`.</sub>

Normally dot `.` matches every character except new line. In Unix only `\n` is new line mark, so other characters like carriage return `\r` are threated as normal characters.

Take a look at this String `"A\r\nB\rC\nD"`. If you will try to find match for regex like`.+` using

```
String data = "A\r\nB\rC\nD";
System.out.println(data);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".+").matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("["+m.group()+"]");
}
```

you will get

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

but if add flag `Pattern.UNIX_LINES` characters like `\r` will also be possible match for `.` and output will change into

```
[A
]
[B
C]
[D]
```

So first match is `[A\r]`, second `[B\rC]` and third `[C]`