# regex to select specific multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to capture group of lines from large number of lines(upto 100 to 130) after a specific term.

here is my code.

```
String inp = "Welcome!\n"
                +" Welcome to the Apache ActiveMQ Console of localhost (ID:InternetXXX022-45298-5447895412354475-2:9) \n"
                +"  You can find more information about Apache ActiveMQ on the Apache ActiveMQ Site \n"
                +" Broker\n"
                +" Name localhost\n"
                +" Version  5.13.3\n"
                +" ID   ID:InternetXXX022-45298-5447895412354475-2:9\n"
                +" Uptime   14 days 14 hours\n"
                +" Store percent used   19\n"
                +" Memory percent used  0\n"
                +" Temp percent used    0\n"
                + "Queue Views\n"
                + "Graph\n"
                + "Topic Views\n"
                + "  \n"
                + "Subscribers Views\n";
        Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("(?<=Broker)\n((?:.*\n){1,7})", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher mtch = rgx.matcher(inp);
        if (mtch.find()) {
            String result = mtch.group();
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

I want to capture below lines from above mentioned all lines in inp.

```
Name    localhost\n
Version 5.13.3\n
ID  ID:InternetXXX022-45298-5447895412354475-2:9\n
Uptime  14 days 14 hours\n
Store percent used  19\n
Memory percent used 0\n
Temp percent used   0\n
```

But my code giving me all lines after "Broker". May I know please what am doing wrong ?

Secondly, I want to understand, ?: means non capturing group but still why my regex((?:.*\n)) able to capture lines after Broker ?

Comment: please don't use slang or shorts in your variables (inp, rgx, mtch) just write it out

Comment: [Remove `Pattern.DOTALL`](https://ideone.com/Xn39Xi)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, tried but still same results...!

Comment: Have you seen https://ideone.com/Xn39Xi?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes....but its showing me all when am running in eclipse..?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Cool , now its working..! Why did you add \\R after (?<=Broker) ?

Comment: Aha, OK, I see. `\\R` helped.

Comment: `((?:.*\n){1,7})` does capture for one simple reason: The outer brackets are a capture group themselves again. If you want to prevent this behavior, you must mark the outer group as non-capture again: `(?:(?:.*\n){1,7})`

Comment: Just curious: what if you use `"(?d)(?<=Broker)\n((?:.*\n){1,7})"` in your code? (Without `Pattern.DOTALL`, does it work?)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Its also working...! What's a purpose of (?d) ?

Comment: I added an alternative solution to the answer. Please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove `Pattern.DOTALL` since it makes `.` match newlines, too, and you grab the whole text with `.*` and the limiting quantifier is needless then.

Besides, your real data seems to contain CRLF line endings, so it is more convenient to use `\R` rather than `\n` to match line breaks. Else, you may use a [`Pattern.UNIX_LINES` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064527/pattern-unix-lines-in-regex-with-java) (or its embedded flag equivalent, `(?d)`, inside the pattern) and then you may keep your pattern as is (since only `\n`, LF, will be considered a line break and `.` will match carriage returns, CRs).

Also, I suggest `trim`ming the `result`.

Use

```
Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("(?<=Broker)\\R((?:.*\\R){1,7})");
// Or, 
// Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("(?d)(?<=Broker)\n((?:.*\n){1,7})");
Matcher mtch = rgx.matcher(inp);
if (mtch.find()) {
    String result = mtch.group();
    System.out.println(result.trim());
}
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/6rlmvc).