# Why matcher.find() for input parameter always return 'false'?

Tags: java, regex

I have a strange situation which I find difficult to understand regarding regex matcher.

When I pass the next input parameter *issueBody* to the matcher, the matcher.find() always return false, while passing a hard-coded String with the same value as the *issueBody* - it works as expected.

**The regex function**:

```
private Map<String, String> extractCodeSnippet(Set<String> resolvedIssueCodeLines, String issueBody) {
        String codeSnippetForCodeLinePattern = "\\(Line #%s\\).*\\W\\`{3}\\W+(.*)(?=\\W+\\`{3})";
        Map<String, String> resolvedIssuesMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (String currentResolvedIssue : resolvedIssueCodeLines) {
            String currentCodeLinePattern = String.format(codeSnippetForCodeLinePattern, currentResolvedIssue);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(currentCodeLinePattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(issueBody);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                resolvedIssuesMap.put(currentResolvedIssue, matcher.group());
            }
        }
        return resolvedIssuesMap;
    }
```

### The following always return false

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(currentCodeLinePattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(issueBody);
```

### While the following always return true

````
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(currentCodeLinePattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("**SQL_Injection** issue exists @ **VB_3845_112_lines/encode.frm** in branch **master**\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Severity: High\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "CWE:89\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "[Vulnerability details and guidance](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "[Internal Guidance](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/AS/pages/79462432/Remediation+Guidance)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "[ppttx](http://WIN2K12-TEMP/bbcl/ViewerMain.aspx?planid=1010013&projectid=10005&pathid=1)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Lines: 41 42 \n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "---\n" +
                        "[Code (Line #41):](null#L41)\n" +
                        "```\n" +
                        "    user_name = txtUserName.Text\n" +
                        "```\n" +
                        "---\n" +
                        "[Code (Line #42):](null#L42)\n" +
                        "```\n" +
                        "    password = txtPassword.Text\n" +
                        "```\n" +
                        "---\n");
````

My question is - why? what is the difference between the two statements?

Comment: Can you also show where/how you are assigning the issueBody string? Maybe something is wrong with that.

Comment: My first guess is that issueBody was created from a byte stream using the wrong charset.

Comment: What is the value of currentCodeLinePattern

Comment: *"Why?"* Because `issueBody` is **not** the same value as that string literal, regardless of your unproven claim that it is. To verify that, print the bytes of both: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(issueBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));` and the same for the string literal, then compare the two.

Comment: I added the whole function. **issueBody** is nothing but a string which related to an issue object...

Comment: Try ``String codeSnippetForCodeLinePattern = "(?d)\\(Line #%s\\).*\\W`{3}\\W+(.*)(?=\\W+`{3})";``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - it doesn't work.. the initial '(?d)' marked as incomplete group structure

Comment: @Andreas - you are right. they are not the same. why is that and what needs to be done?

Comment: Hm, and `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(currentCodeLinePattern, Pattern.UNIX_LINES);`? Note `Pattern.MULTILINE` is not necessary as your pattern has neither `^` nor `$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - it worked! I guess I never would have though the `Pattern.MULTILINE` is the problem... thanks!

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR:*

**By using `Pattern.UNIX_LINES`, you tell Java regex engine to match with `.` any char but a newline, LF.** Use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(currentCodeLinePattern, Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
```

In your hard-coded string, you have only newlines, LF endings, while your `issueBody` most likely contains `\r\n`, CRLF endings. Your pattern only matches a single non-word char with `\W` (see `` \\W\\`{3} `` pattern part), but CRLF consists of two non-word chars. By default, `.` does not match line break chars, so it does not match neither `\r`, CR, nor `\n`, LF. The `` \(Line #%s\).*\W\`{3} `` fails right because of this:

- `\(Line #%s\)` - matches `(Line #<NUMBER>)`
- `.*` - matches 0 or more chars other than any line break char (up to CR or CRLF)
- `\W` - matches a char other than a letter/digit/`_` (so, only `\r` or `\n`)
- `` \`{3} `` - 3 backticks - these are only matched if there was a `\n` ending, not `\r\n` (CRLF).

Again, by using [`Pattern.UNIX_LINES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064527/pattern-unix-lines-in-regex-with-java), you tell Java regex engine to match with `.` any char but a newline, LF.

BTW, `Pattern.MULTILINE` only makes `^` match at the start of each line, and `$` to match at the end of each line, and since there are neither `^`, nor `$` in your pattern, you may safely discard this option.