# replace `\\r` with `\r` in string

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to convert all the occurrences of `\\r` to `\r` in string.

My attempt is following:

```
    String test = "\\r New Value";
    System.out.println(test);
    test = test.replaceAll("\\r",  "\r");
    System.out.println("output: " + test);
```

Output:

```
\r New Value
output: \r New Value
```

Comment: Ohh yes, i will edit it in a minute, Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `replaceAll` you would have to use `.replaceAll("\\\\r", "\r");` because

- to represent `\` in regex you need to escape it so you need to use pass `\\` to regex engine
- but and to create string literal for single `\` you need to write it as `"\\"`.

Clearer way would be using `replace("\\r", "\r");` which will automatically escape all regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used for escaping in Java - so every time you actually want to match a backslash in a string, you need to write it twice.

In addition, and this is what most people seem to be missing - `replaceAll()` takes a regex, and you just want to replace based on simple string substitution - **so use `replace()` instead.** (You can of course technically use `replaceAll()` on simple strings as well by escaping the regex, but then you get into either having to use `Pattern.quote()` on the parameters, or writing 4 backslashes just to match one backslash, because it's a special character in regular expressions as well as Java!)

A common misconception is that `replace()` just replaces the first instance, [but this is not the case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

> Replaces **each substring** of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

...the only difference is that it works for literals, not for regular expressions.

In this case you're inadvertently escaping `r`, which produces a carriage return feed! So based on the above, to avoid this you actually want:

```
String test = "\\\\r New Value";
```

and:

```
test = test.replace("\\\\r",  "\\r");
```

Comment: I need to use replaceAll() since there can be more `\\r` in string, i have posted a test string for keeping the question to the point.

Comment: @GauravGupta You misunderstand replace - it does replace each occurance, not just the first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)
The only difference is that it takes a *literal* replacement rather than a regex, which in this case is what you want.

Comment: let me try it with replace() also.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape each of the `\` symbols.

Try:

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\\\r",  "\\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

Character `\r` is a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) :)

- [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

To print `\` use [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)`\`

```
System.out.println("\\");
```

### Solution

Escape `\` with `\` :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "\\\\r New Value";
    System.out.println(test);
    test = test.replaceAll("\\\\r",  "\\r");
    System.out.println("output: " + test);
}
```

result

```
\\r New Value
output: \r New Value
```