# End of line character / Carriage return

Tags: c, file, text, carriage-return, end-of-line

I'm reading a normal text file and write all the words as numbers to another text. When a line finishes it looks for a "new line character (\n)" and continues from the new line. In Ubuntu it executes perfectly but in Windows (DevC++) it cannot operate the function. My problem is the text in Windows which I read haven't got new line characters. Even I put new lines by my hand my program cannot see it. When I want to print the character at the end of the line, it says it is a space (ascii = 32) and I am sur that I am end of the line. Here is my end of line control code, what can I do to fix it? And I read about a character called "carriage return (\r)" but it doesn't fix my problem either.

```
c = fgetc(fp);
printf("%d", c);
fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_SET);
if(c == '\n' || c == '\r')
    fprintf(fp3, "%c%c", '\r', '\n');
```

Comment: The windows line seperator is "\r\n".

Comment: How can I mention it together in if statement I don't know it, like '\r\n' ) @ElliottFrisch

Comment: The problem is Windows doesn't use a single character at end of line. It uses two. First a carriage return ('\r') then a new line ('\n'). Ancient versions of Mac (e.g. pre X) used '\r' alone.

Comment: `\r\n` was what you actually sent to terminals and printers to get a new line; still is, to terminal/console emulators.  There is no ASCII newline, `\n` is translated to ASCII LF, linefeed without carriage return; its interpretation as newline on unix is entirely conventional.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n/9549183#9549183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are opening a text file and want newline conversions to take place, open the file in `"r"` mode instead of `"rb"`

```
FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
```

this will open in text mode instead of binary mode, which is what you want for text files.  On linux there won't appear to be a difference, but on windows, `\r\n` will be translated to `\n`

A possible solution it seems, is to read the numbers out of your file into an `int` variable directly.

```
int n;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
```

unless the newline means something significant to you.

Comment: I tried to open the file both in "rb" and "r"; there is no difference. My text haven't got new lines I think, but I put them by myself too. I don't understand the problem. Can the problem is about text file?

Comment: @mrtgnccn if it doesn't have newlines then why are you checking for `\n`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of questions here

1. What is the difference between windows text newline and unix text newline?

   UNIX newline is LF only. ASCII code 0x0a.
   Windows newline is CR + LF. ASCII code 0x0d and 0x0a
2. Does your file have LF or CR ?

   Use a hex editor to see the contents of the file. I use xxd on linux.

   ```
   $ xxd unix.txt
   0000000: 0a0a 
   $ xxd windows.txt
   0000000: 0d0a
   ```