# What is the difference between these files?

Tags: r, qualtrics

I am writing an R script to program a [Qualtrics](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/advanced-options-drop-down/import-and-export-surveys/) survey from an Excel template I created. I grab the survey items from the Excel [template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8rq1ds2zaumb5b/template.xlsx) via the `xlsx` package and then do a bit of munging to create a `.txt` file formatted the way I want it. The problem is that I can't upload it to Qualtrics unless I select all in the resulting `.txt` file, copy, and paste into a blank `.txt` file.

**This is not a question about Qualtrics**, per se, and I don't think one needs to know anything about this platform to consider the question. I believe that my problem is in the R output file format. I hope if you continue reading, you will see what I mean.

Everything in the following code block should work.

```
require(xlsx)
# import survey file; get from Dropbox link above
  survey <- read.xlsx("template.xlsx", "survey")
  survey <- subset(survey, !is.na(survey$questiontext)) # drop if blank
  choices <- read.xlsx("template.xlsx", "choices")
# create vector to hold results
  output <- "[[AdvancedFormat]]"
# loop through every question
  for (i in 1:nrow(survey)) {
    # insert start block if one exists
      bs <- ifelse(is.na(survey$blockname[i]), "", 
                   paste0("[[Block:", 
                          as.character(survey$blockname[i]), "]]"))
    # insert end block if one exists
      be <- ifelse(is.na(survey$endblock[i]), "", 
               as.character(survey$endblock[i]))
    # insert item ID if one exists
      qid <- ifelse(is.na(survey$questionid[i]), "", 
                    paste0("[[ID:", 
                           as.character(survey$questionid[i]), "]]"))
    # subset choice sheet to selected choice
      choices.sub <- subset(choices, choices$listname==survey$choicelist[i])
      responses <- ""
    # create vector of choices
      for (ch in 1:nrow(choices.sub)) {
        responses <- paste(responses, choices.sub$label[ch], sep="\r") 
      }
    # insert page break if one exists
      pb <- ifelse(is.na(survey$pagebreak[i]) | i==nrow(survey), "", 
                   as.character(survey$pagebreak[i]))
    # add to output vector
      output <- paste(output, 
                      bs,
                      survey$questiontype[i],
                      qid,
                      survey$questiontext[i],
                      survey$choicetype[i],
                      responses,
                      pb,
                      be,
                      sep="\r")
  }
# write to txt file
  cat(output, file = (con <- file("foo1.txt", "w", encoding = "UTF-8"))); close(con)
```

Here's the resulting [foo1.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2g6fwir9kdpq2aq/foo1.txt) file from R. Qualtrics rejects this file. If I select all from this file and copy into a new blank `.txt` file (using ST3), [foo2.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpw8iqs5ov052xt/foo2.txt), Qualtrics is happy.

What is different about these two files? I'm not changing anything in `foo2.txt`. Just copy/paste into a new file.

Comment: I haven't checked your solutions, but from the top of my head, are there any special characters not visible? What about encoding? If you're using UTF, do you use BOM?

Comment: I don't think there are any hidden characters, unless my carriage returns `\r` count. I specified "UTF-8" in `file()` because the default format of Sublime Text 3 is "default_encoding": "UTF-8". I figured since `foo2.txt` works and since `foo2.txt` is in UTF-8, it would work.

Comment: Here's what I found about BOM in `?file`: "As from R 3.0.0 the encoding "UTF-8-BOM" is accepted and will remove a Byte Order Mark if present." I tried using `encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"`, but I got an error: `unsupported conversion from 'UTF-8-BOM' to ''`. This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) makes me think it should not be required. But I'm not sure.

Comment: It makes me wonder what happens when you save the new `.txt` file. What program do you use to save it?

Comment: Sublime Text 3 (Mac). Just command-A, command-C, command-N, command-V, command-S.

Comment: This is almost always a conflict between `<CR>` and `<CR>-<LF>` as end-of-line terminators.

Comment: Thanks, @CarlWitthoft. You prompted me to search for `R` and end-of-line terminators. I stumbled upon this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) and the discussion of `\r` vs `\n`. Changing my `\r` to `\n` did the trick.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.  Go ahead and either answer your own question or mark it as a dupe if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CarlWitthoft pointed me in the right direction with his comment:

> This is almost always a conflict between `<CR>` and `<CR>-<LF>` as end-of-line terminators.

I searched on the topic and found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) that led me to change my `\r` to `\n`. That did the trick.