# Creating a percent counter in terminal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal

I want to create a fake percent counter within terminal in Ruby somewhat like this:

```
percent = 0
(1..100).each{|x| sleep(0.05); print "#{percent+=1}%"}
```

How do I make it so that instead of printing percent over and over again it just increasing the value of percent by 1 but stays "in place".

Please note that this is for aesthetic purposes only.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the carriage return character (e.g `\r`) to the end of the string, this has the effect of clearing the line before you write to it again.

```
percent = 0
(1..100).each{|x| sleep(0.05); print "#{percent+=1}%\r"}
```

What it actually does is a bit more complex and there's a good [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n).