# jscs error : validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at filename.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jscs

After `grunt-jscs` it gives following errors for `base/index.js` file.

```
Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at api/v1/base/index.js :
     1 |var errors = require('restify-errors');
-----------------------------------------------^
     2 |function Base(Model) {
```

After I remove `var errors = require('restify-errors');` this line, it starts giving below error

```
Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at api/v1/base/index.js :
     1 |function Base(Model) {
------------------------------^
```

How to resolve this?

**Workaround found** : Created new file and copied all content to it resolves the problem.

Still want to know any specific reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

this is probably an issue with [line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)
You might want to put `"validateLineBreaks": null` into your `.jscsrc` file

Answer (score 1):

If your .jscsrs is with the rule 
`"validateLineBreaks":"LF"`, 
It means you must use `LF` as line breaks, if you are using other line break symbol (such as `CRLF`), JSCS will give you an error like:

> validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at api/v1/base/index.js :

There're two ways to resolve the problem, one is to change the jscs' rule, and the other is to always use LF as line breaks.

You can find the different between `LF` and `CR` in this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Mistype: it's `.jscsrC` :)

Answer (score 0):

tldr;
Change between LF an CRLF, if you are using VScode you can do this by clicking the option at the bottom right:
[image: Click there and select the porper option at the top]

Detailed: As tomato said, the issue is probably that the line break format of your IDE isn't compatible with jscs, from the eslint documentation:

> The linebreaks (new lines) used in windows operating system are
> usually carriage returns (CR) followed by a line feed (LF) making it a
> carriage return line feed (CRLF) whereas Linux and Unix use a simple
> line feed (LF). The corresponding control sequences are "\n" (for LF)
> and "\r\n" for (CRLF)

You can also try adding `*.js text eol=lf` to your .gitattributes file if you know this won't affect the project in any meaningful way.

You can read more about the issue here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style