# In Bash, how can I output a new line after read -es?

Tags: linux, bash, newline

current code:

```
echo -n "password: "
read -es password
echo -n "ok"
```

behavoir in linux:

```
password: ok
```

Can we make it like:

```
password:
ok
```

thanks,
wxie

The following will work:

```
read -p "password: " -es password
echo
echo "ok"
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe:

```
read -p "password: " -es password
printf "\n ok \n"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a newline before the OK, this should do it:

```
echo -e "\nok"
```

The `-e` enables interpretation of the backslash codes.

Answer (score 1):

From echo's man page: `-n    do not output the trailing newline`. Try it without the option.

Comment: Thanks, but you need try it first. -n is intended for doing password: xxx(cr). Without -n the output would be password: (newline).

Comment: @wxie, on bash version 3 and bash version 5, `help read` describes the `-n` option for `read` to be: "If -n is supplied with a non-zero NCHARS argument, read returns after NCHARS characters have been read." So, `read -n` does not seem to relate to passwords and newlines as you say.

Comment: @wxie, I see you may be talking about `echo -n`, not `read -n`. Please ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `\n` [as a line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) in `printf`, there is an extra line for padding after "ok" which you can remove

```
printf "password: " && read -es password && printf "\n\nok\n"
```

If you are saving a password this way it would still be contained in the variable `$password` in plain text, the string below would print it openly.

```
printf "$password"
```

Your code sample uses `echo` and should be using `printf`, there are [articles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on echo's POSIX compliance, `echo` could work like Greg Tarsa points out, but not all versions are built with switch options like `-e` or `-n`.

I find it *readable* to use `printf`, also other "languages" have similar commands such as [PRINT, print, println, print() and others](https://excelwithbusiness.com/blog/say-hello-world-in-28-different-programming-languages/).

If you need to use echo you could

```
echo -n "password: " && read -es password && echo -e "\nok\n"
```