# C++ server and java client chat

Tags: java, c++, server, client, chat

;)

I write a chat program with c++ server and java client.

The code of the function that responsible to receiving messages from the client is:

```
void *recieve(void* *v)
{
    while (true)
    {
        bzero(buffer, 256);
        n = read(socketfd, buffer, 256);
        if (n < 0)
            exit(1);
        printf("Client: %s", buffer);
    }
}
```

the code of the function thar responsible to send messages to the server is just:

```
ps.println(msg);
```

where ps is a printstream.

When I send a message to the server, say "hello world" the c++ server print:
"Client: hello worldClient".

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.
(I apologize if my English is not good)
thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using write and writing only the number of bytes read ? And as Joachim said, don't forget the null terminating byte x)

Comment: By the way, you miss an important case in your error checking of the `read` call: You do not handle disconnects properly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg doesn't [`bzero()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) ensure that the null terminator will be there if less than 256 bytes are received ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) function will return 0 when it reaches the end of file.

So in your case, there is a first loop iteration that receives `"Hello world"`,  then there's one more iteration, that will receive nothing but `read()` returns 0.  So "Client :" is displayed with an empty string.

In addition, be aware that:

- with socket based communication, it is not guaranteed that one `read()` on the server side will correspond to one `println()` on the client side. So for longer messages, you'll risk to receive it in pieces.  On the output you'd then see several "Client" within the message text.
- the line separator sent [on the java side](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) might not necessarily correspond to the [line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279802/3723423) expected on the server side, expect if you're working cross-platform.