# How to remove CRLF from the end of nodepad++?

Tags: windows, git

Last night I have installed `Git` in my local machine which runs through `Windows 10`. `Git` replaces all new line by `CRLF`.

Today morning I just installed `Nodepad++` software. While I hit `Enter` button for a line break it puts an extra `CRLF` at the end of each line. [Please look at the attached figure]

[image: CRLF in nodepad++]

I have uninstalled my `Git` also but the problem remains as it before. Let me know, what should I do right now to hide `CRLF` from the last of each line?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In case it helps: http://superuser.com/questions/409919/cr-and-lf-characters-at-end-of-line-in-notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with Git itself. These characters indicate the end of line. Read this question: [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) to learn more about them.

You have to toggle "Show End of Line" setting of Notepad++ as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/409919/cr-and-lf-characters-at-end-of-line-in-notepad) if you don't want to see these special characters anymore.