# SQL Remove Carriage return

Tags: mysql, sql

The data I am extracting contains carraige returns, I am not able to export the data and do any analysis on it.

i.e

```
Select system_outcome , contact_list_name , agent_classification , timestamp_dtm , phone_number, agent_name
From call_stats_view
Where date(timestamp_dtm) BETWEEN '2016-11-10' AND '2016-11-10'
```

This should give me a

```
Answered, Contactlist1, Sale, 2016-11-10, 07777777777, John King
```

when i extract the information it all ends up on different lines any idea how i can get around this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Workbench (mysql)

Answer (score 8):

You should try something like the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(yourColumn, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

to be certain that you remove all end of lines (CR & LF).

**NOTE:** you may considering replacing with ' ' (blank) if some useful information is separated by end of line only, otherwise you might get joined words.

Comment: What is CR and LF?

Comment: White spaces that expand your string on multiple lines. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) for more details.

Comment: @JoyиalAli Carriage Return and Line Feed

Comment: @Alexei do i have to do that for every column?

Comment: @JoyиalAli - Yes. Another option is make the client perform the replacements. If you want the correction in Workbench, check [these options](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/options.html#options-multiline).