# Python 3 adding extra tags to string while reading data over Arduino Serial Port (myserial)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I am JUST now learning some python after running through a 30 episode series of arduino programming. The runner-up python series I am following seems to be a little out-dated as far as the package modules go and I've seen some strange syntax things happening that aren't occurring in the original video material.

The objective for this lesson was to get Python to read a String counter over Arduino's serial port.

Counter for Arduino over serial port (Code):

```
int cnt=0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("I am counting ");
  Serial.print(cnt);
  Serial.println(" Mississippi");
  cnt=cnt+1;
  delay(1000);
}
```

Read from serial port in PyCharm (Code):

```
import serial

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com4', 9600)

while (1==1):
    if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        print (myData)
```

Terminal Results:

```
b'I am counting 0 Mississippi\r\n'
b'I am counting 1 Mississippi\r\n'
b'I am counting 2 Mississippi\r\n'
b'I am counting 3 Mississippi\r\n'
```

What are the b \r \n tags. and why does it apply some automatic formatting like 'string'? This does not happen in his videos.

Also, on Python's side of things the `print (myData)` was formatted as `print myData` without (). It would not even compile otherwise but it worked fine in his video. Are these just changes in the syntax from updating from Python 2 to Python 3?

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return and `\n` is a newline, might want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279802/1971401)

Comment: Nothing has been added to your data and you are not using a string, you are using byte objects - that's what the `b` means when you try to print one.  One of the differences between python 2 and 3 is that python 2 strings *were* byte objects, but python 3 strings are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\r` is the carriage return character and `\n` is new line

they originate in the

```
   Serial.println(" Mississippi");
```

line of your arduino code, notice how `.println` is different from `print`

the `b` in front of the string indicates that this is a byte string, if instead of

```
print(myData)
```

you do

```
print(myData.decode())
```

you should no longer see them

Comment: `print(str(myData))` will not get rid of the `b` prefix, you need  `print(myData.decode())`

Comment: thanks for mentioning that @cdarke, i have made a correction

Answer (score 0):

RE: Arduino Sketch:
"\r\n" are return and newline characters, respectively.

Because your arduino sketch uses 'Serial.println' instead of 'Serial.print', you have these characters.

RE: Python
You are running python 3, there for you have byte-strings being return (b'byte string'). So yes, the tutorial to which you do not link uses python 2.