# Mysql: Varchar(3) can't find input when I select something that is 2 characters long

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `code` VARCHAR(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`)
);
```

As you can see the primary key of this table is the word `code`
When I try to select a specific code in this table, that is 2 characters long, it cannot find anything.

On the other hand, when I select a 3 characters long code like this:
`` select * from `country` where `code` = "TZA"; ``

I get the result I want

I searched for my variable in the table (for example the code "AL") and it appears to be registered.

[image]

Why is this happening and how could I make it work?

Thank you in advance!

I am importing my data from a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path_to_file\\countries.csv'
INTO TABLE `country`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(`name`, `code`);
```

I have tried selecting with a space in the end of the `code` and on the front of it:

```
select * from `country` where `code` = 'AL ';
select * from `country` where `code` = ' AL';
```

But they output nothing

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7?

Comment: Does not seem to be a problem? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6a08b6dbffec9ed90d89402d9295b49b

Comment: It is unclear what your REAL problem is.  Just saying that `select * from `country` where `code` = "TZA";` produced the result you want, and stating that `"AL"` seems to be registered is not enough.   What do you want to do ?

Comment: Well. I tried it myself, inputing data with a query and It works. I am gonna change my question because I am inputing data from a csv file

Comment: Your data probably contains "AL " (a space as third character) and not "AL".   you could fix that using `update country set code=trim(code);`

Comment: @Luuk I did that update function, but the response was this: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 248  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
As I mention above I have tried both selecting the "AL " and " AL"
My ultimate problem is that the column `code` is used in an other table (as a foreign key) in which I cannot add anything that has not a 3 characters long `code` column

Comment: Try `SELECT code, HEX(code) FROM country WHERE code like '%AL%';`..    The HEX(code) should produce `414C`, but probably you will get `414C0D` (or something else).

Comment: @Luuk That worked and the hex value is: 414C0D. It appears it has a space in front of it.
How can I get rid of that (trim() did not work)?

Comment: `update country set code=replace(code,'\r','');`.   this should work because `select hex('\r');` produces `0D`.

Comment: By the way, `\r` means it's not a 'space' (as in the space bar). Here, [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n). And refer [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83aad700240dfc57402edc769d1cfee8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution is:

When importing this CSV file you should use:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path_to_file\\countries.csv'
INTO TABLE `country`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(`name`, `code`);
```

Because your lines seems to be terminated the way Windows terminates lines.