# Why \n line feed works in find and \r carriage return works in replace as new line?

Tags: regex, vim, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I got a file with text in this format. (with unwanted line spaces)

```
1

2

3
```

Now I wanted to use **vim** to remove those unwanted lines with this command `:%s/\n\n/\n/g`. replacing two new lines with one. But got this result:

```
1^@2^@3
```

then I found out about **carriage return** and used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) to change the command to `:%s/\r\r/\r/g` and got this error saying `E486: Pattern not found: \r\r`

then I used this working command `:%s/\n\n/\r/g` and got the desired result.

```
1
2
3
```

How is this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\r` in the pattern matches a carriage return (CR) char, not any line break char. The `\r` construct should used in the replacement pattern to replace with a newline.

So, you can use either

```
:%s/\n\n/\r/
```

or, to replace chunks of any two or more newline chars with a single newline:

```
:%s/\n\{2,}/\r/
```

To account for CRLF endings, you can use

```
:%s/\v(\r?\n){2,}/\r/
```

that matches two or more (`{2,}`) sequences of an optional CR char (`\r?`) and then a newline, line feed (LF) char.